# How to collect non-ascii characters with Psychtoolbox in Octave?

Tags: octave, psychtoolbox

I'm trying to program an experiment in which participants type in words using the keyboard. I've tried to use the functions `GetString()`, `Ask()` and `GetEchoString()`. However, none of these functions seem to be able to collect non-ASCII characters, in particular German "Umlaute" (i.e., "öäüß").

For example, when I type the word "Lösung" as a response to `x = GetString()`, then I get `x = Lsung` (the "ö" is not registered). Similar problems arise when using `Ask()`, `GetEchoString()` or `GetChar()`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

My system info:

```
Octave version: 4.2.2
Psychtoolbox version: 3.0.14
OS: Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: out of curiousity, does it work with `input('Please enter word: ', 's')` at the terminal?

Comment: @Tasos: I just tried your suggestion "input('Please enter word: ', 's')" and typed in "Lösung". This seems to work - the "ö" was registered and I got "Lösung". So, it seems to be a Psychtoolbox problem...

Comment: excellent. so for now if what you're really after is a graphical way to obtain input, perhaps you can simply rely on octave's native GUI facilities (or just use `input` if you're ok with asking your users to use the terminal). Also, I would encourage you to submit a bug at Psychtoolbox